# capture words from string with python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture the number of months from the string. So what I want is 2 or two. I did:

```
s = '2 month free two month free'
re.findall(r'(\d|\w) month free',s)
```

What I got is `['2', 'o']`. It seems that I was not able to capture the whole word 'two'. Can anyone know why? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add plus `+` after `\w` to match the whole number.

```
s = '2 month free two month free'
re.findall(r'(\d|\w+) month free',s)
```

Output:

```
['2', 'two']
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the `+` to specify there's one or more characters

```
import re
s = '2 month free two month free'
print(re.findall(r'(\d+|\w+) month free',s))
```

Output:

```
['2', 'two']
```